# Installing GoCD Agent with Yum fails with `sysvinit-tools` not found

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, yum, ec2-ami, go-cd

I'm' trying to install GoCD Agent with `sudo yum install -y go-agent`
However, I'm getting the following error.

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package go-agent.noarch 0:19.6.0-9515 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sysvinit-tools for package: go-agent-19.6.0-9515.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: go-agent-19.6.0-9515.noarch (gocd)
           Requires: sysvinit-tools
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried installing `sysvinit-tools` with `sudo yum install sysvinit-tools`

I'm getting the following error.

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                                                        | 2.1 kB  00:00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                     | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
No package sysvinit-tools available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I'm on `Amazon Linux AMI`

Answer (score 2):

In your case you appear to be on `Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03` which is rather old and does not have sysvinit-tools.

I would recommend upgrading your machine, and to avoid upgrading sysvinit manually.

## for centos7:

you can find that package in the **epel** repositories

First add the **epel** repository:

```
yum install epel-release
```

now you will be able to install sysvinit-tools:

```
yum install sysvinit-tools
```

Comment: on what os are you?

Comment: When I ran `cat /etc/os-release`  I get  `Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03`

Comment: that os seems to be based on centos6, at least I see it only has epel-release-6 which does not have sysvinit-tools...

Comment: you might try finding the package online and installing it (eg: https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/sysvinit-tools-2.87-6.dsf.el6.x86_64.rpm.html), but since I don't really know what it does exactly I don't know if that is a good idea.

Comment: I tired that too, but got this.
```
warning: sysvinit-tools-2.87-6.dsf.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
 sysvinit-tools < 2.88-8 conflicts with (installed) util-linux-2.23.2-33.28.amzn1.x86_64
 sysvinit-tools is obsoleted by (installed) sysvinit-2.87-6.dsf.15.amzn1.x86_64
```

Comment: I adapted my answer.